# Convert to DateTime in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a strange format that I need to convert to an Oracle Timestamp (no fractal seconds needed).  I have two columns, date_entered, and time_entered, that have this format from our AS/400:

```
1110729 954
1110811 1216
1110815 1526
1110815 1659
1110817 1007
1110818 1000
1110821 1715
1110822 1320
1110823 1852
1110825 1743
1110826 1100
1110826 1559
1110826 1711
1110826 1906
```

The Date Column is an AS/400 date, with the 1st character as a y2k mark YYYMMDD.  All dates are actually above year 2000, so that 1st character can be disregarded if needed.

Also, as you can see my time_entered field is a 24-hour timstamp, however it is a "number" field, so 3-digit rows are possible.  I would like to write a SQL statement to convert this to an Oracle Timestamp.  Not a function or anything, but just select statement to select the datetime of these two columns combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an Oracle instance and Sparky is correct with just a few minor modifications. Need to change the '+' to '||' and also need to change the 'hh' to 'HH24':

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(datefield,2)||LPAD(timefield,4,'0'),'YYMMDDHH24MI')
```

Sample shown below:

```
SQL> describe oldvalues2
 Name                                     Null?    Type
 ---------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DATEVAL                                           VARCHAR2(7)
 TIMEVAL                                           VARCHAR2(4)

SQL> select * from oldvalues2
  2  /

DATEVAL TIME
------- ----
1110729 954
1110826 1906

SQL> select to_timestamp(substr(DATEVAL,2)||lpad(TIMEVAL,4,'0'),'YYMMDDHH24MI')
  2  from oldvalues2
  3  /

TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(DATEVAL,2)||LPAD(TIMEVAL,4,'0'),'YYMMDDHH24MI')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
29-JUL-11 09.54.00.000000000 AM
26-AUG-11 07.06.00.000000000 PM
```

Comment: Thanks, I did fix the HH to HH24, but forgot about the concatenation character being different.   I appreciate you noticing and fixing it.   Been a while since I've worked in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
select To_TimeStamp(substr(datefield,2)||lpad(timefield,4,'0'),'YYMMDDHH24MI') 
From table
```

I don't have oracle on this machine, but the above should work for you.